# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the WithdrawService

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

The architecture of the application is quite simple, two controllers from the main application.

- App (main service)
- Deposit (controller + service)
- Withdraw (controller + service)

In some cases, the Deposit Service must run a function of the Withdraw Service, so it initializes the Withdraw Service. All worked very will till I added the MongoDB part.

It started to fail when I added the constructor to the Withdraw Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class WithdrawService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('withdraw') private withdrawModel: Model<WithdrawDocument>){}
```

Withdraw.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WithdrawController } from './withdraw.controller';
import { WithdrawService } from './withdraw.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { WithdrawSchema } from './dto/withdraw.dto';


@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'withdraws', schema: WithdrawSchema }])],
  controllers: [WithdrawController],
  providers: [WithdrawService, ],
  exports: [WithdrawService]
})
export class WithdrawModule {}
```

deposits.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DepositsController } from './deposits.controller';
import { DepositsService } from './deposits.service';
import { UtilsModule } from '../utils/utils.module';
import { WithdrawModule } from '../withdraw/withdraw.module';
import { DepositSchema } from './dto/deposit-dto';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { WithdrawSchema } from '../withdraw/dto/withdraw.dto';

@Module({
  imports: [UtilsModule, WithdrawModule, MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'deposits', schema: DepositSchema }])],
  controllers: [DepositsController],
  providers: [DepositsService]
})
export class DepositsModule {}
```

deposit.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class DepositsService {

    constructor(private withdrawService: WithdrawService,
```

...

The problem is when the DepositsService is trying to initialize the WithdrawService, any clue how I can solve that?

Error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the WithdrawService (?). Please make sure that the argument withdrawModel at index [0] is available in the WithdrawModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If withdrawModel is a provider, is it part of the current WithdrawModule?
- If withdrawModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within WithdrawModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing withdrawModel */ ]
  })
```

**Before adding the constructor to the WithdrawService and the mongoDB part, the two services where able to communicate**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `WithdrawModule` you are using `MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'withdraws', schema: WithdrawShcema }])` but in your `WithdrawService` you are using `@InjectModel('withdraw')`. Under the hood, the `forFeature` creates the injection token `withdrawsModel` andthe `@InjectModel()` sets the metadata for the injection token as `withdrawModel`. These tokens don't match, so Nest can't determine what to inject. You either need to change the `MongooseModule` to use `withdraw` (singular) or you need to change the `@InjectModel()` to use `withdraws` (plural)